# Unterschied zwischen »des Nachts«, »nachts«, »bei Nacht« und »in der Nacht«?

Tags: meaning, difference

Besteht zwischen diesen Ausdrücken ein Unterschied?

> Er arbeitete *des Nachts*.
>
> Er arbeitete *nachts*.
>
> Er arbeitete *bei Nacht*.
>
> Er arbeitete *in der Nacht*.

**Ergänzung:**

> Er arbeitete *nachtsüber*.
>
> Er arbeitete *während der Nacht*.

Comment: Zur Bildung von _des Nachts_: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8853 (englisch)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Des Nachts* ist archaisch. (Es ist so ungewöhnlich, daß ich nicht sicher gewesen wäre, ob man es großschreibt.)

*Nachts* ist modern und *normal* (linguistisch ausgedrückt: unmarkiert).

*Bei Nacht* ist gehoben und „atmosphärisch“; üblicherweise beschreibt man zum Beispiel Ölgemälde mit *Paris bei Nacht*, nicht Dienstpläne.

*In der Nacht* impliziert tendentiell eine einmalige Handlung, während die anderen eher eine habituelle Bedeutung transportieren: *in der Nacht* kann leicht zu einer genaueren Angabe erweitert werden, zum Beispiel „in der Nacht zum 14. Oktober“, was mit *bei Nacht* nicht möglich ist.

*Nachtsüber* ist zwar genau nach dem Muster von *tagsüber* gebildet, aber derart selten, daß es mir in meinen 42 Jahren als Muttersprachler nie begegnet ist. Meine einzige Konnotation dazu ist „seltsam“.

*Während der Nacht* ist eine völlig normale Präpositionalphrase. Es spricht nichts dagegen, sie zu verwenden, außer daß es bereits das sinngleiche, unmarkierte *nachts* gibt.

Die Unterschiede bestehen also fast nur in der Konnotation; die Spanne zwischen Sonnenuntergang und -aufgang beschreiben sie alle gleichermaßen.

Comment: "Er hat **immer** in der Nacht gearbeitet." – Es wirkt nur so, dass "in der Nacht" sich auf eine einmalige Handlung bezieht, weil hier notwendig ist, dies durch Kontext oder Schlagwörter genauer zu konkretisieren.

Comment: Nach meinem Wörterbuch ist "daß" auch archaisch. Ist es noch benutzt?

Comment: @Arc676 Nur von Leuten, die vor 1996 sozialisiert wurden (so wie ich)...

Comment: Nacht ist ein Nomen. Deutsch ist die einzige Sprache in der man alle Nomen groß schreibt

Comment: @Jonas: Was soll uns der Kommentar sagen?

Comment: Was bedeutet wiederum: "Er arbeitete über die Nacht"?